# Postgres Large Table Slow Performance

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database in AWS RDS and have multiple tables that have over 1 mil rows.

I will use one table as an example -

Table A has two columns - let's assume the column names are column_1 and column_2, and both UUID columns.  Both columns have an index on them.  I created the index using a command similar to -

```
CREATE INDEX table_a_column_1_idx on table_a (column_1);
```

If I do a straight select against this table, such as -

```
SELECT COLUMN_1 FROM TABLE_A
```

It takes 30+ secs to return.

Without going into further detail, the structure of the table can't change at this point, i.e. I know there are issues with using UUID, but, I can't change the data type at this point.

What options are there (looking for path with least resistance) to improve query performance here?  Should I add a different type of index?  Change any parameters/settings?

EDIT -

explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select column_1 from table_a

Results -

```
"Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..34706.00 rows=2000000 width=16) (actual time=0.005..208.549 rows=2000000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=14706"
"Planning Time: 0.026 ms"
"Execution Time: 317.561 ms"
```

Comment: There is no `WHERE` in your `SELECT`, so it requires a full table scan anyway and indexes aren't really helpful there.

Comment: This is a scenario where I need to retrieve all of the rows in this table.  Are there any suggestions on improving performance for full table scans?

Comment: Better hardware... Or maybe less load on the machine all together from other processes than Postgres, i.e. terminate the others and maybe change Postgres' configuration to claim more resources. But that may be not possible due to the hosting.

Comment: This is in AWS - db.m6g.16xlarge,vCPU: 64, RAM: 256GB

Comment: By far the speed of the disk (seek time) and lesser the bus to it are interesting here. Then memory, then maybe network (depending on where the result is supposed to go in the end)...

Comment: When you have no WHERE clause, you've asked for all rows, and it has to hit each row to provide it. Your index is meaningless without a WHERE or ORDER BY - the index would be used to identify rows to include when you use the WHERE, and to order the data correctly when you use an ORDER BY. You have neither of those, so the index is ignored entirely and the DBMS will return rows however it decides to do  so.

Comment: @Chris What are you doing where you "*need to retrieve all of the rows in this table*"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated question to include the execution plan

Comment: The table contains a list of users and I have to perform an operation for each user.  @Bergi I know the alternative is for the code to do this in batches, i.e. retrieve n rows at a time, process operation, and then proceed to the next batch, but was curious in general if I can update the configuration or add something that could result in the rows being returned in less than 30 secs

Comment: The query runs in 300 **milli**seconds on the server. The difference between the 30 seconds you see and the 300ms is the time it takes to send the rows (roughly 30MB) over the network and for your application (or SQL client) to process them. There is not much you can do if you really do need all those 2000000 rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would the suggestion then be to modify the instance type to one that boosts the network speed?  I am connected through a jumphost with my Postgres client just for debugging purposes, but the actual code that retrieves this data is a lambda function that is in the same VPC as the RDS instance